# Building an application through Android Studio, I keep getting the following errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Firstly I'd like to say I'm new to coding, only been doing it for the past year in Java, below are the errors. I don't know where to look within my program for it to post my code, so as to not be posting unnecessary code. Any additional help would be grateful. Thanks in advance :)

```
    1231-1231/mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    1231-1231/mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
    1231-1231/mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames.mostwantedgames E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

EDIT: My application is simple. It allows users to store information on their phone. A bug I get which I can't figure out how to fix is when a user types into the top line the "add button" is supposed to be able to be clicked, however it's doing the complete opposite.

I've attempted removing the code and seeing if that works but the error still persists.

MainActivity code:

```
        gameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(gameTxt.getText()).trim().isEmpty());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to supply a lot more information -- a few error messages without any context about what symptoms you're seeing, what you've attempted to do to solve the problem, or the nature of your code isn't enough for you to get much help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to the emulator? Because i get those type of error mainly when running my apps with Genymotion.
The solution that works for me is just uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: I do use Genymotion, but I got the same error while using my phone which is strange.